# Looking for fast way to get Listitem Count

Tags: linq, sharepoint-server

My problem ist related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551807/add-item-count-to-linq-select).
In order to get the basic statistics I need the total item count. However the basic LINQ query

```
(from t in Tickets
select t).Count();
```

or

```
Tickets.Count();
```

does take a considerable amount of time (5-10 seconds on my laptop-vm, depending on load).
Are there quicker ways to get the count, or is this huge timespan caused by the lack of resources on my machine?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this, its part of that sharepoint object model SPList.ItemCount:

```
    private static void OpenListItem(string siteURL, string listName)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists[listName];

                Console.WriteLine(list.ItemCount.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
```

change it to suite your needs, I just made it in a console app :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.itemcount.aspx

its designed for a fast and efficent count, if you want the exact ammount use:

```
    private static void OpenListItem(string siteURL, string listName)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists[listName];

                Console.WriteLine(list.Items.Count.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only two faster way that I know are:

- use CAML
- have an hidden column that keep the number of your records

otherwise I found this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/6a98b55c-2454-49c0-beb8-a57fe9b8b25a/

I had wrote this post where I thought that another way could be use the search service.